# How many commas should one be using here?

Tags: punctuation

Would tomorrow, 10 PM, work?

Would tomorrow, 10 PM work?

Would tomorrow 10 PM work?

Are all these sentences grammatically correct? Do we use two commas or one? Or none?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Elements of date and time are generally separated by commas, for example:

> I went to Chicago on Saturday, September 26, 2020, to visit my mother.

Of course, you don't necessarily 'hear' such punctuation in spoken English. If you are trying to more accurately capture the feel of the spoken word, you could instead ask:

- Would tomorrow at 10pm work?
- Would tomorrow work, at 10pm?
- Would 10pm tomorrow work?